# How to fetch and display multiple rows data into a gridview dynamically using asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've inserted multiple rows data from gridview to database at a time using stored procedure.

Now I've to fetch and display that multiple rows data into GridView and inside GridView I need to call particular value from column to a particular label into GridView.

How can I get that values dynamically? I am not seeing any way to show data.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you better define what you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: I'm not getting any way to do this. i'm confused.
Dynamically Means I've inserted more than 1 rows value into database with any primary key. and on selection this primary key I've to fill gridview data with multiple row values.

Comment: I doubt you've inserted more than 1 row with the same primary key.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class structure. This class is passed in and defining variables for the value. Define a list of this class type. Add the individual values ​​from the database to this list. Assign this list variable to the GridView's Datasource

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of articles out there just go and have a try.
[Databinding](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-GridView-with-DataReader-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Secondly, you mentioned

> I need to call particular value from column to a particular label into
>   GridView.

I mean on when? after binding or there should a button and it's click event do that stuff?

Comment: I've inserted more than 1 row values into database with any primary key. and on selection this primary key value, I've to fill gridview data with multiple row values. and I took Primary key into a dropdownlist.
OnSelectedIndexChange event I've to fill gridview rows data.

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier there are tons of article regarding this..please check this link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Display-data-in-GridView-based-on-DropDownList-Selected-value-Selection-in-ASPNet.aspx   second thing is you cannot insert more than 1 row having same pk.